# Unexpected "{" in a long code line that is located in a code with many if's and if-else structures are mixed together?

Tags: r, if-statement, curly-braces

When trying to write a function `fromNdpTo10` that converts normalized double precision number (in memory) to decimal number, I get "`unexpected '{' in:`" error, but I should not get that error. I cared the opening and closing number of paranthesis, braces, brackets to be equal. Look:

```
SubstringHoldingLeading0s <- function(x) { 
  x <- formatC(x, flag="0", width=11, format="d") 
  substr(x, 1, 11) 
}
SubstringHoldingLeading0s(00100101101) # "00100101101"

from2to10 <- function(binaryNumber) {
  # Via SubstringHoldingLeading0s, the loss is prevented when converting string (holded as numeric) to character
  sapply(strsplit(SubstringHoldingLeading0s(binaryNumber), split = ""), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x) * 2^(rev(seq_along(x) - 1))))}
from2to10(00100101101) # 301

fromNdpTo10 <- function(NdpNumber) {
  NdpNumber <- as.character(NdpNumber)
  out <- list()

  # Handle special cases (0, Inf, -Inf)
  If (NdpNumber %in% c(
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "0111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "1111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")) {
    # special cases
    If (NdpNumber == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000") { out <- "0" }
    If (NdpNumber == "0111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000") { out <- "Inf" }
    If (NdpNumber == "1111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000") { out <- "-Inf" }
  } else { # if NdpNumber not in special cases, begins

    signOfNumber <- "+" # initialization
    If (substr(NdpNumber, 1, 1) == 0) { signOfNumber <- "+"
    } else { signOfNumber <- "-" }

    # From BiasedExponent to RealExponent (Biased Exponent=Real exponent +1023;  Real exponent=Biased Exponent-1023)
    BiasedExponent <- substr(NdpNumber, 2, 12)
    BiasedExponent <- from2to10(BiasedExponent)
    RealExponent <- BiasedExponent - 1023


    # Significand
    Significand <- substr(NdpNumber, 13, 64)
    Significand <- from2to10(Significand)

    out <- paste0(c(signOfNumber, Significand, "e", RealExponent), collapse = '')
  } # if NdpNumber not in special cases, ends

  out
}
```

The error is:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"        "0111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "1111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")) {"
```

The problem seems to be caused by long code in single line. Is there a limit for characters in a single line? Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: It should probably be `if (...` note the upper-case `If` in your code.

Comment: I changed the question by correcting all lowercase if to capital If. The same error persists. Now, after simple BIG error was corrected, the question should remain in SOF. See the changes in question.

Comment: @markus, I changed  all lowercase `if` to capital `If`. The same error persisted. I changed the content and title of the question that reflects the new situation exactly. So, the reason "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" is not valid anymore.

Comment: It should be `if` NOT `If` - try `If (1 %in% 1:3) { print("Hello World!") }`

Comment: Many many thanks markus. I misunderstood the correction offer 180 degree reverse! Now, it works. I should have seen my BIG own error since RStudio was not highlighting my Ifs...!  Now, I will delete this question completely from SOF in a little while!

Comment: My deletion of my question was rejected by SOF. The message popped up is: `You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.`. I looked help center, and could not figure out what to do with this question.

Comment: Glad it works now. Nevermind the closing of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
If (substr(NdpNumber, 1, 1) == 0) { signOfNumber <- "+"
```

'if' is written with lower starting case 'i'.

As a piece of advice, try to follow common coding style conventions (variables with lower case first letter, ...)